# Azure build fail if branch doesn't have latest master

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I have the following bash script written in Azure pipeline:

```
if [[ "$(Build.Tag)" == "blabla" && "$(Build.SourceBranch)" != *"blabla"* ]];
then
   run some git command to get the diff between current branch and master 
   if branch doesnt have the lastest master fail the build
else
   echo "Passed"
fi
```

I want to fail the build of the current branch if it does't have the latest changes from master.
Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this question? Please check whether my answer below can help you and feel free to comment~

Answer (score 0):

> I want to fail the build of the current branch if it does't have the latest changes from master. Is there any way to do it ?

Yes. Here is an example:

```
      if [ -z "$(git diff origin/bran1 origin/bran2)"]
      then 
        echo "ERROR!"
        echo "ERROR" > logfile.log
        exit 125
      fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this REST API [Get Changes Between Builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20changes%20between%20builds?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1), it will get the changes made to the repository between two given builds. if the build commit ID is same, the response body count value is 0.

Add task power shell and enter below script:

```
$PAT="$(pat)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))
          
#Get the previous build commit id
$GetPreviousURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/build/builds?definitions={Build definition ID}&api-version=6.1-preview.6"
$GetPreviousBuild = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $GetPreviousURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get 
$PreviousBuildID=$GetPreviousBuild.value.id[1]
#Write-Host $PreviousBuildID

#Get the changes made to the repository between two given builds
$CompareBuildURL= "https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/build/changes?fromBuildId=$($PreviousBuildID)&toBuildId=$($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER)&api-version=6.1-preview.2"

#Write-Host $CompareBuildURL

$CompareBuildResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $CompareBuildURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get 
$Count = $CompareBuildResult.count
#Write-Host $Count

#If the count is 0, fail this build
if ($Count.equals(0)) { 
        throw 'it does not have the latest changes from master (exit 1)'
   }
```

**Result**:

it does not have the latest changes.

[image]

it have the latest changes.

[image]

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?